# Цвет параграфа не изменяется через JS. Ошибка: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')

Tags: javascript, dom

не могу понять почему не хочет изменяться цвет параграфов по клику. Есть 4 блока во флексбоксе. Хочу по клику на первый блок изменять цвет текста параграфов в нём. Но, либо выходит ошибка:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')
at HTMLDivElement.firstBlock.onclick

Когда код такой:

```
<div class="each_block first_block"><p>GitPod is incredibly cool.</p>
                    <p>In my opinion, this is a big step in open source software contribution. I'm excited to see where we go from here.</p>
                        <div class="signature">
                            <img src="img/Ben.png">
                                <p class="signature_p">
                                    <b>Ben Halpern</b>
                                        <br>
                                    Creator and Co-founder
                                        <br>
                                    <b>@forem</b> and <b>@ThePracticalDev</b>
                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS код добавлен ниже блоков в HTML

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        // нахожу элемент по классу
            let firstBlock = document.querySelector('.first_block');
        // В классе назожу параграфы 'p'
            let paragraph = firstBlock.getElementsByTagName('p');

        // По клику мыши хочу изменить цвет текста по всех 'p' на красный

            firstBlock.onclick = function() {
                paragraph.style.color = 'red';
                // Вывод в консоль просто чтобы видеть действие 
                    console.log('Whats wrong?');
                }
        </script>
```

Либо меняется цвет только первого параграфа когда меняю код на этот:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        // нахожу элемент по классу
            let firstBlock = document.querySelector('.first_block');
        // В классе назожу параграфы 'p'
            let paragraph = document.querySelector('.first_block p');

        // По клику мыши хочу изменить цвет текста по всех 'p' на красный

            firstBlock.onclick = function() {
                paragraph.style.color = 'red';
                // Вывод в консоль просто чтобы видеть действие 
                    console.log('Whats wrong?');
                }
        </script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том как изменить цвет текста внутри всех тегов 'p' ?

Если я изменю строку кода на :

```
let paragraph = document.querySelectorAll('.first_block p');
```

Останется та же ошибка:

index2.html:256 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color') at HTMLDivElement.firstBlock.onclick

И если так тоже:

```
let paragraph = document.querySelectorAll('p');
```

Хотя последняя запись изначально некорректная, т.к.мне нужно искать все 'p' в конкретном блоке. Но и при такой записи ошибка повторяется:

```
let paragraph = firstBlock.querySelectorAll('p');
```

Comment: Для нахождения всех элементов Вам нужен [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), так как `querySelector()` возвращает первый элемент документа, который соответствует указанному селектору или группе селекторов.

Comment: Ну а для `getElementsByTagName()` он возвращает коллекцию элементов, а не конкретный элемент которому можно было бы поменять style.

Comment: Если я изменю строку кода на : 

let paragraph = document.querySelectorAll('.first_block p');

Останется та же ошибка: index2.html:256 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')
    at HTMLDivElement.firstBlock.onclick 

И если так тоже: 

let paragraph = document.querySelectorAll('p');

Хотя последняя запись изначально некорректная, т.к.мне нужно искать все 'p' в конкретном блоке

Но и при такой записи ошибка повторяется: 

let paragraph = firstBlock.querySelectorAll('p');

Comment: Естественно, так как Вы пытаетесь задать свойство `color` для [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList), а не конкретному элементу, для того чтобы сделать это для конкретного элемента, нужно сделать перебор элементов из NodeList, обратиться к каждому элементу данной коллекции и тп, например используйте метод `forEach()`. Просто выведите в консоль `document.querySelectorAll('.first_block p');`, может так будет понятнее что это.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте для наглядности прикреплю пример. Собственно что не так в Вашем коде, у Вас есть ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color') at HTMLDivElement.firstBlock.onclick
```

Ошибка говорит о том что невозможно установить несуществующее свойство. Собственно в случае с `getElementsByTagName('p')`, если обратиться к [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) данный метод возвращает Вам [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) с которой Вы пытаетесь работать как с элементом, тоже самое и с [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) где Вам возвращается [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Для того чтобы работать и взаимодествовать с  элементами внутри коллекции, нужно сделать перебор и обратиться к конкретному элементу из коллекции, для NodeList можете использовать метод `forEach()`, для HTMLCollection Вам будет нужно его преобразовать либо посредством `Array.from(htmlCollection)`, либо `[...htmlCollection]`, где Вы уже сможете воспользоваться методами `forEach()` или `map()`.

```js
const firstBlock = document.querySelector('.first_block');
// В классе назожу параграфы 'p'
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.first_block p');

// По клику мыши хочу изменить цвет текста по всех 'p' на красный

firstBlock.onclick = function() {
  paragraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
    paragraph.style.color = 'red';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="each_block first_block">
  <p>GitPod is incredibly cool.</p>
  <p>In my opinion, this is a big step in open source software contribution. I'm excited to see where we go from here.</p>
    <div class="signature">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150">
        <p class="signature_p">
            <b>Ben Halpern</b>
                <br>
            Creator and Co-founder
                <br>
            <b>@forem</b> and <b>@ThePracticalDev</b>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```